# ASP.NET MVC 2 - Authentication form doesn't fire the action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Hi have a form that call an Action properly. But when i enable the authentication forms, the action to login doesn't fire up (i test it with a breakpoint).

My Web.config is:

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="Autenticacao/Index"></forms>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
```

It's in the view **Index** of controller **Autenticacao** where i have my form:

```
    <% Html.BeginForm("Login", "Autenticacao"); %>
    <input type="text" id="autenticacaoReferencia" name="autenticacaoReferencia" /><br />
    <input type="text" id="autenticacaoPassword" name="autenticacaoPassword" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Entrar" />
    <% Html.EndForm(); %>
```

The controller **Login** is sucefully called just if the authentication form is disable.

Am i using the BeginForm in a wrong way?

Edit: The Login action:

```
    public ActionResult Login(string autenticacaoReferencia, string autenticacaoPassword, string returnUrl)
    {
    ...
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: When you enable forms authentication and "the action to login doesn't fire up," what actually happens?  Does it just stay on the login form?  Also, can you show your `Login` action controller code?

Comment: Hi Kirk. It doesn't happen nothing, i guess it was redirecting agains to "Index" instead of "Login". I've removed the users="?" and now it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you decorating your actions with the `[Authorize]` attribute?

Comment: Do i need an atribute in the Action "Login"? I'm just using the [Authorize] in the class's i need user to be authenticated

Comment: I've removed the users="?" from denny and it's working now. (it's reendirecting to Authentication page when it's not authenticated as well.